# VBA - Chart series number of values limitation

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, charts

I am trying to plot an array which is in the order of 10.000 or more values, but the chart is only plotting almost a 10th of those numbers.
The arrays `engSpdPoints` and `indTrqPoints` have more than 10.000 values but when I check the data on the graph it only shows me less than 2.000 data points.

```
Set residencySrs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With residencySrs
    .XValues = engSpdPoints
    .Values = indTrqPoints
    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    .Name = residency(1)(4)
End With

With .Axes(xlCategory)
    .HasTitle = True
    .AxisTitle.Caption = "Eng Speed (rpm)"
    .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0"
End With

With .Axes(xlValue)
    .HasTitle = True
    .AxisTitle.Caption = "Torque (Nm)"
    .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0"
End With
```

End With

It would be great not to have the data stored in a range of cells in another sheet.

Comment: Where is code where you load the arrays ?     `.XValues = engSpdPoints
    .Values = indTrqPoints`

Comment: what do you mean? I can see in the debugging area that there are thousands of values.

Comment: There are limits to using arrays for charts because there is a limit to the length of the SERIES formula for a chart series, and hardcoded values from an array can eat this up very quickly. If you can, you'd be better off putting the data into a range somewhere.

Comment: If I do that, wouldn't I need to keep the range stored? I mean I could not delete it otherwise the series disappears for the chart.

Comment: Why do you need to delete the range after plotting it? What's wrong with storing the data in the worksheet? That's how Excel charts work best.

Comment: @JonPeltier because it will ocupy space and due to the amount of data I am requiring the file would become huge. The idea is to plot the data in a graph and move the graph to other place which may be a PowerPoint presentation, Word or another Excel file.

Comment: You don't think the chart itself, storing the data internally, will also become very large? How about keeping the data in a worksheet, making a chart of this data, then pasting a copy as a picture into Word or PowerPoint?

Comment: Revisiting this after a separate discussion. In the current latest beta channel release of Excel for M365, a VBA array of up to 16,384 elements can be used to populate a chart series. More elements are discarded. I can plot a million points from the worksheet, and I suspect the limit is 1,048,576, the number of rows in a worksheet. A workbook with two columns of data, with 16384 X and Y values, and no chart is 418 kb. The workbook with all points charted is 730 kb. A workbook with no data, with the chart populated by VBA is 255 kb. So there is some saving, but these are not large files.